# It makes any difference to write linq with the where clause on top or on bottom

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, linq

I'm writing some linq queries and I'd like to know if there's any difference on the order of the clauses.
For instance:

```
lstParam.Where(p => p).Select(p => p).ToList<Type>();
```

or

```
lstParam.Select(p => p).Where(p => p).ToList<Type>();
```

By difference I mean in performance or in development standard.
Can anyone give a short explanation?

Comment: It depends on which you need to do first... transform the data or filter the data.  Filtering is usually better performed earlier in the sequence, since it results in fewer records being operated on in later operations.  But logically that isn't always an option.

Comment: @M.kazemAkhgary The `Select` does nothing, but the `Where` doesn't.  If he passed `p => true` *then* that would do nothing.  Currently it'd need to be a sequence of booleans, and it'd yield all those that are `true`.

Comment: Oops. Yes you are right @Servy however my main point was filtering first is better but you may not be able to always directly filter first.

Comment: @M.kazem Akhgary you're write it was a too simple example. But thanks for all the responses

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your `.Where` is dependent on the changes made in the `.Select`, then it would have to go after it(1).  If your `.Select` would throw an exception on records that didn't match the `.Where`, then the where must go first(2).  If your `.Where` wants to use properties that aren't passed through the `.Select`, then the `.Where` must go first(3).

You can do multiple .Select and .Where as well...

```
var a=x.Select(p=>p).Where(p=>p).Select(p=>p);
```

In general, if order is not important to completion, then `.Where` first is faster if things don't get optimized.  That is because a new object won't need to be instantiated for anything that fails the `.Where`.  That said, in the vast majority of cases of using an IQueryable on a database, it makes no difference at all (speed wise, if the order is not important).

Example 1:

```
var result=x.Select(p=>new Person { Name=p.First+" "+p.Last })
  .Where(p=>!String.IsNullOrEmpty(p.Name)); // works
var result=x.Where(p=>!String.IsNullOrEmpty(p.Name))
  .Select(p=>new Person { Name=p.First+" "+p.Last }); // Does not work
```

Example 2:

```
var result=x.Select(x=>new {DollarsPerDay=x.Dollars/x.Day})
  .Where(x=>x.Day>0); // may throw exception when day == 0
var result=x.Where(x=>x.Day>0);
  .Select(x=>new {DollarsPerDay=x.Dollars/x.Day}) // works
```

Example 3:

```
var result=x.Select(p=>new Person { Name=p.First+" "+p.Last })
  .Where(p=>p.Age>18); // Doesn't work
var result=x.Where(p=>p.Age>18)
  .Select(p=>new Person { Name=p.First+" "+p.Last }); // Works
```

Comment: Thanks @Robert McKee. It's quite an explanation.

Answer (score 1):

An entity projection in a `Select` doesn't do anything.  Removing it entirely wouldn't change the program at all (beyond making it a tinsy bit faster) and adding additional such projections to the query, at any point, also does nothing (beyond make the program a tinsy bit slower), so whether your no op is before or after the where is irrelevant.

The performance different is highly unlikely to matter in either case, but if you really care, just remove it entirely.

Comment: In the example I gave here it makes no difference, but I have some more complex queries where I use the Select clause to mount the output object.
Like: Select(p => { ID = p.ID})

Comment: @KingClauber I couldn't possibly comment on all of the possible effects of any two unknown operations changing order.  There are all sorts of things that could possibly happen, and no way of ever describing all of them.